# How to pass current date in raw sql in sqlalchemy execute

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to update a datetime column in mysql database. The application uses sqlalchemy but for some reason I have to pass a raw sql here. The query is

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.execute(text("update table set col1=:value, date=:curr_date"),{'value:' my_value, 'curr_date:' func.now()})
```

The query throws an error `expected string or buffer` near `'curr_date:' func.now()})` . How do I format the return value to string? Even if I do format it to string, how would it be converted to datetime when inserted into database?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest reading up a bit on [SQLAlchemy's `TextClause.bindparams`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.bindparams). I think that may be what you're looking for. For the current datetime, I'd recommend just using `datetime.datetime.now()`. Please see below:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
import datetime

stmt = text("UPDATE test_table SET name=:value, update_date=:curr_date WHERE id=:the_id")
stmt = stmt.bindparams(the_id=1, value='John', curr_date=datetime.datetime.now())
session.execute(stmt)  # where session has already been defined
```

Using the following environment, I tried the above code with a session and it worked just fine:

```
OS X El Capitan
MySQL Server 5.7
PyMySQL (0.7.2)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.12)
Python 3.5.1
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am aware of `datetime.datetime.now()`. I am looking for something using func.now().